# JWT token service returning error when passing through rails middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, middleware, rack

I'm trying to build a middleware that will verify the role a user has. This will be made decoding the token, searching the `user_id` and checking if the role that user has is 'admin' or other, and with that, protect different endpoints.

I was able to access the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header that has the token (the format is "Bearer token") and assign a variable to it (only the token, not the "Bearer" part) but when I call the decode method in the token service, it returns the error:

> JWT::DecodeError (Not enough or too many segments)

Here's the code:

`ownership.rb` middleware:

```rb
class Ownership
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end

  def call env
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    
    token = env.select {|k,v| k.start_with? 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'}
    .collect {|key, val| "#{val.split.last}"}

    user_id = AuthTokenService.decode(token)

    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, user_id]

  end

end
```

`AuthTokenService`

```rb
class AuthTokenService
  def self.call(user_id)
    id = { user_id: user_id }
    JWT.encode({
                id: id,
                exp: 3.hours.from_now.to_i 
      }, ENV['HMAC_SECRET'], ENV['ALGORITHM_TYPE'])
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    decoded_token = JWT.decode token, ENV['HMAC_SECRET'], true, { algorithm: ENV['ALGORITHM_TYPE'] }
    decoded_token[0]['id']
  end
end
```

If I return the token in the response, this is the format:
ex.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjozfSwiZXhwIjoxNjM4MzAxMjE1fQ.kzcWc1xeHbKbzxCuRkS2cvuKlxPBtib6ChgR-jY_WNw
```